# Add another PropertyResourceConfigurer programatically with spring-boot

Tags: spring, groovy, gradle, spring-boot

We're setting up an advanced/complex multimodule build with gradle, groovy and spring-boot.

In addition to using @EnableAutoConfiguration to automatically pick up application*.yml files, we would like to register a "custom" PropertyResourceConfigurer to handle common properties placed in a separate "config" module which can be reused across several spring- boot apps.

However, when adding the following in a @Configuration annotated class, startup fails with an exception

```
@Configuration
class CommonConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

 @Bean (name = 'geit')
    PropertyResourceConfigurer geitProperties() {
        PropertyResourceConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();

        Resource[] resources = new Resource[env.activeProfiles.length];
        println "Environment2 : ${env}"
        env.activeProfiles.eachWithIndex() {
            env, i -> resources[i] = new UrlResource(getURL(String.format("classpath:environment/%s.properties", env)))
        }

        configurer.setLocations(resources)
        return configurer
    }

}
```

the exception is

```
4fa8a851930816b4d09ecb1/springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:57)
2014-11-04 14:13:56.975 ERROR 48941 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:168)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.getProperty(NullCallSite.java:44)
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'geit' defined in class path resource [geit/config/CommonConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer geit.config.CommonConfig.geitProperties()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'activeProfiles' on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:601)
    at geit.config.CommonConfig.geitProperties(CommonConfig.groovy:55)
    at geit.config.CommonConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c13414af.CGLIB$geitProperties$21(<generated>)
    at geit.config.CommonConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c13414af$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e7b06e5c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFaat geit.config.CommonConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c13414af.geitProperties(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
ry.java:1008)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    ... 22 more
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:150)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:692)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:962)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:951)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at geit.AdminApplication.main(AdminApplication.groovy:19)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer geit.config.CommonConfig.geitProperties()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'activeProfiles' on null object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'activeProfiles' on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.getProperty(NullCallSite.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at geit.config.CommonConfig.geitProperties(CommonConfig.groovy:55)
    at geit.config.CommonConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c13414af.CGLIB$geitProperties$21(<generated>)
    at geit.config.CommonConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c13414af$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e7b06e5c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at geit.config.CommonConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c13414af.geitProperties(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.iate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

However, when adding the following to CommonConfig

```
 @Bean
    public String profileConfigBean() {

        println "Environment : ${env}"

        env.activeProfiles.each {
            println it
        }

        'devprofilebean'
    }
```

this correctly prints all active profiles.

Even adding an empty PropertyResourceConfigurer causes startup to fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a working solution.

I added a class annotated with @PropertySource for each environment pluss one for default properties.

examples: 
One for DEV

```
@Configuration
@Profile(Profiles.DEV)
@PropertySource("classpath:/environment/dev.properties")
class CommonDevConfig {

}
```

and the one for default

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/environment/default.properties")
class CommonConfig {

}
```